# Lex pattern for recognizing IPV6 addresses

Tags: c, token, lex, flex-lexer

I have a pattern that is given below to match an ipv6 address in the dotted quad notation.

```
IPV4ADDRESS (([[:digit:]]{1,3}"."){3}([[:digit:]]{1,3}))
hex4         ([[:xdigit:]]{1,4})
hexseq       ({hex4}(:{hex4}*))
hexpart      ({hexseq}|({hexseq}::({hexseq}?))|::{hexseq})
IPV6ADDRESS  ({hexpart}(":"{IPV4ADDRESS})?)
```

and I use

```
%x S_rule S_dst_ip

<S_rule>(dst-ip){SPACE}   {

           BEGIN(S_dst_ip);

        }


<S_dst_ip>\{{IPV6ADDRESS}\}  {

       /*code to process the sring here.*/
     }
```

to match an input of the form

```
dst-ip {3ffe:1900:4545:3:200:f8ff:fe21:67cf}
```

the given regular expression does not seem to match the above pattern for some reason.Could someone be kind enough to point out the error in my code.

Can someone point out the error in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `*` might be in the wrong place:

```
hexseq       ({hex4}(:{hex4}*))
```

Is this what you meant?

```
hexseq       ({hex4}(:{hex4})*)
```